How can i check flutter apk type [ release or split-apk: arm64-v8a... ]
Actually, I'm trying to implement in-app updates because I don't want to distribute the app on Google Play. In this approach, I want to provide users with a split ABI APK according to their supported ABI instead of a universal release APK. Since my app size is up to 50 MB, offering split APKs is a better option.
The below function works fine, but I'm encountering issues when updating the app. Specifically, if I already have a non-split APK release version installed and then try to update to the latest version, the device checks its ABI and downloads the appropriate APK. However, during installation, I get the error "App not installed" due to incompatible APK formats. For example, having a full APK and then downloading a split APK causes this error. This issue affects all APK/ABI scenarios, making this feature impractical.
Here is my code:
/**
 * Checks for updates of the app and shows a dialog to update if a new version is available.
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * Example:
 * ```dart
 * checkForUpdates(context);
 * ```
 */
Future<void> checkForUpdates(BuildContext context) async {
  // Get the current app version
  String currentAppVersion = await getCurrentAppVersion();
  print("the current package version: $currentAppVersion");
  // Get the list of supported ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces) of the device
  List<String> supportedAbis = await getDeviceABIs();
  // Create an instance of the FeatureService
  final FeatureService featureService = FeatureService();
  // Fetch the app update content from the server
  List<AppUpdate> appUpdateContent = await featureService.fetchAppUpdate(context);
  // Initialize variables to store the latest version and APK URL
  String apkUrl = '';
  String latestVersion = '';

  // Iterate through the app update content
  for (AppUpdate appUpdateInfo in appUpdateContent) {
    print("the latest package version: ${appUpdateInfo.appVersion}");
    // Check if the app update is the latest version and is newer than the current version
    if (appUpdateInfo.isLatest && appUpdateInfo.appVersion.compareTo(currentAppVersion) > 0) {
      // Update the latest version and APK URL based on the device's ABI
      latestVersion = appUpdateInfo.appVersion;
      if (supportedAbis.contains("arm64-v8a")) {
        // Use the arm64-v8a APK URL
        apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.arm64_v8a;
      } else if (supportedAbis.contains("armeabi-v7a")) {
        // Use the armeabi-v7a APK URL
        apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.armeabi_v7a;
      } else if (supportedAbis.contains("x86_64")) {
        // Use the x86_64 APK URL
        apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.x86_64;
      } else {
        // Use the release APK URL as a fallback
        apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.release;
        return; // Exit the function early
      }
    }
  }

  // Check if a new version is available
  if (latestVersion.compareTo(currentAppVersion) > 0) {
    // Show the update dialog and handle the download process
    showUpdateDialog(apkUrl, latestVersion);
  }
}

Is there a way to determine the type of APK already installed, such as release, split ABI, or debug, so I can provide the correct APK URL? For instance, if the armeabi-v7a APK is installed, the latest update should also be the armeabi-v7a APK.

To determine the type of APK currently installed (split or universal) and ensure compatibility during updates, you can use the following approach:
Step 1: Check the Current APK Type
Create a function to determine if the installed APK is a universal APK or a split ABI APK.
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<String> getCurrentApkType() async {
  // Initialize PackageInfo to get the current package info
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;

  // Use Platform channels to get the sourceDir of the APK
  const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.app/sourceDir');
  final String sourceDir = await platform.invokeMethod('getSourceDir', {'packageName': packageName});

  // Check if the APK contains specific ABI-related files
  bool isSplit = false;
  Directory apkDir = Directory(sourceDir);
  List<FileSystemEntity> files = apkDir.listSync();
  for (FileSystemEntity file in files) {
    if (file.path.contains("arm64-v8a") || file.path.contains("armeabi-v7a") || file.path.contains("x86_64")) {
      isSplit = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Return the APK type
  return isSplit ? 'split' : 'universal';
}

Step 2: Update checkForUpdates Function
Modify your checkForUpdates function to use the APK type and provide the appropriate APK URL.
Future<void> checkForUpdates(BuildContext context) async {
  // Get the current app version
  String currentAppVersion = await getCurrentAppVersion();
  print("the current package version: $currentAppVersion");
  
  // Get the current APK type (split or universal)
  String currentApkType = await getCurrentApkType();
  print("the current APK type: $currentApkType");
  
  // Get the list of supported ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces) of the device
  List<String> supportedAbis = await getDeviceABIs();
  // Create an instance of the FeatureService
  final FeatureService featureService = FeatureService();
  // Fetch the app update content from the server
  List<AppUpdate> appUpdateContent = await featureService.fetchAppUpdate(context);
  // Initialize variables to store the latest version and APK URL
  String apkUrl = '';
  String latestVersion = '';

  // Iterate through the app update content
  for (AppUpdate appUpdateInfo in appUpdateContent) {
    print("the latest package version: ${appUpdateInfo.appVersion}");
    // Check if the app update is the latest version and is newer than the current version
    if (appUpdateInfo.isLatest && appUpdateInfo.appVersion.compareTo(currentAppVersion) > 0) {
      // Update the latest version and APK URL based on the device's ABI and current APK type
      latestVersion = appUpdateInfo.appVersion;
      if (currentApkType == 'universal') {
        // Use the release APK URL
        apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.release;
      } else {
        if (supportedAbis.contains("arm64-v8a")) {
          // Use the arm64-v8a APK URL
          apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.arm64_v8a;
        } else if (supportedAbis.contains("armeabi-v7a")) {
          // Use the armeabi-v7a APK URL
          apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.armeabi_v7a;
        } else if (supportedAbis.contains("x86_64")) {
          // Use the x86_64 APK URL
          apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.x86_64;
        } else {
          // Use the release APK URL as a fallback
          apkUrl = appUpdateInfo.release;
          return; // Exit the function early
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Check if a new version is available
  if (latestVersion.compareTo(currentAppVersion) > 0) {
    // Show the update dialog and handle the download process
    showUpdateDialog(apkUrl, latestVersion);
  }
}

Explanation

getCurrentApkType Function:

This function uses PackageInfo and platform channels to get the source directory of the installed APK.
It checks for specific ABI-related files to determine if the APK is split or universal.

Updated checkForUpdates Function:

The function now includes a call to getCurrentApkType and uses this information to decide the appropriate APK URL for the update.
It ensures that the update APK matches the type of the currently installed APK, preventing compatibility issues.
By following this approach, you can smoothly update your app from a universal APK to a split ABI APK or vice versa without encountering the "App not installed" error.
Hope it works!
